# Using Jpeg UI layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on creating an educational app, like a preschool app for kids.
The interface should look something like this

[image: UI Layout]

If you can see from my picture, there are a 2x3 sets on left and right and a midle dispaly.
There are 3 buttons underneath the top section and on the bottom section there is a 2x5 table.

I figured if I could create this UI, make it a Jpeg, and move it to my drawable folder, I could apply it to my project then work on top of it.
That did not quite go as I expected, as when I started adding buttons to the corresponding table cells and run the program - They came up all over the place.

I then realized Android wasn't treating my jpeg as a layout.
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the direction to fix this please?
Should I even forget about bringing in this jpeg in and just try to create it in Android?

Comment: you can make buttons background or src using your jpegs not only jpeg files. if you upload your XML file, it is better for understand your issue.

Comment: @ ST : Thanks for the quick answer. I am not trying to create a button background though. I want to create buttons inside my table cells but I want  each button to stay in their cell nicely. When I run the project - The buttons show up all over the place. It's obvious that the jpeg is being viewed simply as a background and not a layout.   I would want my jpeg to work just like a GridLayout where I can insert buttons in there nicely, and stay nice after running the program.  Hope I am making sense enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your ui using gridLayout.

simply use

```
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
```

I make this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<GridLayout
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button3" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="button4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
</GridLayout>


<GridLayout
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
</GridLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button13" />
</GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this xml will show this. you can change buttons whatever as you want. and make background your jpeg.

[image]

Comment: @ ST: I appreciate the input, I am doing it like you said, only difference is I am using image button instead of regular ones. Your input did help me  in figuring out what I needed to do.  Thanks a lot! I am thinking  the final answer is I cannot bring in jpeg as layout in Android , UI must be designed within.